# create a dataframe from multiple list

Tags: python, pandas

I have several list:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
c = [7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I would like a dataframe with 3 columns named automatically using names of the lists

```
a b c
1 5 7
2 6 8
3 7 9
4 8 10
```

How to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Pandas DataFrame from a list using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
c = [7, 8, 9, 10]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a, b, c)),
                  columns =['a', 'b', 'c'])

print(df)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: is there a way to name the columns automatically as there are many lists with long names? Thanks

Comment: that 'columns' argument is the one

Comment: If you wanted to have string "names" associated with the lists, you should have built a `dict` in the first place, instead of separately named lists.